# Lines connected the cells in organisation chart hard to be adjusted

Tags: tikz-trees, node-connections

I am working with preparation of proposal and currently deal with some issue in organisation chart in Latex.

```
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=center, minimum height=2.5em]

\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[
criteria/.style={text centered, text width=3cm, fill=gray!50},
attribute/.style={%
    grow=down, xshift=0cm,
    text centered, text width=3cm,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.225) |- (\tikzchildnode.center)}},
first/.style    ={level distance=8ex},
second/.style   ={level distance=16ex},
third/.style    ={level distance=24ex},
fourth/.style   ={level distance=32ex},
fifth/.style    ={level distance=40ex},
sixth/.style    ={level distance=48ex},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=11em}]
    % Main Goal
    \node[anchor=center]{Committee Members}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    % Criteria and Attributes
    child{node [criteria] {Project Advisor}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Name}}}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child{node (crit1) [criteria] {Group Leader}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Name}}}
    child{node [criteria] {Assistant Group Leader}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Namen}}}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child{node (crit1) [criteria] {Department of Logistics}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Namen}}
        child[attribute,second] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,third]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fourth] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fifth]  {node {Name}}}
    %
    child{node [criteria] {Department of Design}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,second] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,third]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fourth] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fifth] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,sixth]  {node {Name}}}
    %
    child{node [criteria] {Department of Publicity}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,second] {node {Name}}     
        child[attribute,third]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fourth] {node {Name}}}
    %
    child{node [criteria] {Sponsorship Coordinator}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,second] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,third]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fourth] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fifth] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,sixth]  {node {Name}}}
    %
    child{node [criteria] {Video Production Team}
        child[attribute,first]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,second] {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,third]  {node {Name}}
        child[attribute,fourth] {node {Name}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Organisation Chart.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: aaa]

I have issue dealing with the line connected between cells, and also it seems difficult to insert new cells in between third and fourth level of chart. I wish to make the following chart in Latex as below picture:

[image]

How do I fix this issue so that the organisation chart looks clear and nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This is not a full answer to your question but to draw your attention on the `forest` package, which is based on Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={draw=black,thick,anchor=center, minimum height=2.5em,
text centered, text width=3cm,s sep+=1em,
where level=1{fill=gray!50}{},
where level=3{fill=gray!50}{},
where level=5{fill=gray!50}{}
}
[Committee Members
 [Project Advisor
  [Name
   [Group leader
    [Name]
   ]
   [Assistant Group leader
    [Name
     [Department of Logistics
      [Name
       [Name
        [Name
         [Name
          [Name
          ]
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [Department of Design
      [Name
       [Name
        [Name
         [Name
          [Name
           [Name]
          ]
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [Department of Publicity
      [Name
       [Name
        [Name
         [Name
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [Sponsorship coordinator
      [Name
       [Name
        [Name
         [Name
          [Name
           [Name]
          ]
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [Video production team
      [Name
       [Name
        [Name
         [Name
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have a hard time deciphering your hand drawn diagram, but it may not be a tree, so neither `trees` nor `forest` may be the optimal choice if it is not. One may use a matrix instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[F/.style={fill=gray!50}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=2em,
nodes={text width=3cm,text centered,draw}] 
(mat)
{
 & & |[F]| unreadable & & \\
 & & Name & & \\
 & |[F]| unreadable &  & |[F]| unreadable & \\
 & Name &  & Name & \\[4em]
 & |[F]| unreadable &  & |[F]| unreadable & \\
 & Name &  & Name & \\
 & Name &  & Name & \\[4em]
|[F]| Dept & |[F]| Dept & |[F]| Dept & |[F]| Dept & |[F]| Dept \\
Name & Name & Name & Name & Name \\
Name & Name & Name & Name & Name \\
};
\draw (mat-1-3) -- (mat-2-3) 
(mat-2-3.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (mat-3-2)
(mat-2-3.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (mat-3-4)
(mat-3-2) -- (mat-4-2)
(mat-3-4) -- (mat-4-4)
(mat-4-2.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) coordinate (aux0) -- (mat-1-3|-aux0) coordinate
(aux1) -- ++(0,-2em) -| (mat-5-2)
(mat-4-4.south) |- (aux1) -- ++(0,-2em) -| (mat-5-4)
(mat-5-2) -- (mat-6-2) (mat-5-4) -- (mat-6-4)
(mat-6-2) -- (mat-7-2) (mat-6-4) -- (mat-7-4)
(mat-7-2.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) coordinate (aux2) -- (mat-1-3|-aux2) coordinate
(aux4) -- ++ (0,-2em) coordinate (aux5) 
(mat-7-4.south) |- (aux4)
foreach \X in {1,...,5} {(aux5) -| (mat-8-\X)
(mat-8-\X.west) -- ++ (-0.5em,0) |- (mat-9-\X) 
(mat-8-\X.west) -- ++ (-0.5em,0) |- (mat-10-\X)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to me it seem that node "Name" should be connected on the left side to common vertical line left from gray nodes. about problems with deciphering ... i didn't understand what op like to draw.

Comment: I am so sorry about my bad drawing. I have made change of the drawing which is clearer now. And also I would like to adjust the node that connected to particular cells.

Comment: @weilam06 I added a proposal that reproduces your drawing (as far as I could read things).